# Jquery displaying items in nested loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to display items belonging to different customers. To this effect, i am fetching data through an ajax call and therefater grouping the data based on each unique customer. I then append the grouped data to my html.

Structure of my grouped data looks like:

```
"John Doe": [
    {
        "Item_id" : 1
        "Item_name": "abc"
    },
    {
        "Item_id" : 2
        "Item_name": "def"
    },
],
"Jane Doe":
    {
        "Item_id" : 3
        "Item_name": "ghi"
    },
    {
        "Item_id" : 4
        "Item_name": "jkl"
    },
]
```

My code looks like:

```
$.each(groupedData, function (key, value) {       
    $('.cust_items').append(`
        <h4 class="mb-0"> ` + key + `</h4>                  
        <table id="dataTable">
            <thead>
                <th>Item No.</th>
                <th>Item Name</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    `);

    $.each(value, function (ky, val) {
        $('#dataTable tbody').append(
            `<tr>
                <td>
                    ` + ky + `
                </td>
                <td>
                    ` + val.Item_name + `
                </td>
            </tr>
        `);
    });
});
```

I am facing an inssue whereby all items are being displayed under the first customer while the data is being displayed correctly under the second customer.

Comment: problem in your structure of grouped data

Comment: @DevsiOdedran sorry, that was a typo. I have updated my question with the appropriate structure as it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing commas after the properties and `Jane Doe` property's objects aren't enclosed in `[]`. Consider changing your `groupedData` object as the syntax isn't right.

Edit: Also adjusted the template string and accessing the table with dynamic id as well.

Sample:

```js
let groupedData = {
  "John Doe": [{
      "Item_id": 1,
      "Item_name": "abc"
    },
    {
      "Item_id": 2,
      "Item_name": "def"
    }
  ],
  "Jane Doe": [{
      "Item_id": 3,
      "Item_name": "ghi"
    },
    {
      "Item_id": 4,
      "Item_name": "jkl"
    }
  ]
};

$.each(groupedData, function(key, value) {
  $('.cust_items').append(`
        <h4 class="mb-0">${key}</h4>                  
        <table id="dataTable_${key.split(' ').join('_')}">
            <thead>
                <th>Item No.</th>
                <th>Item Name</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    `);

  $.each(value, function(ky, val) {
    $(`#dataTable_${key.split(' ').join('_')} tbody`).append(
      `<tr>
                <td>
                    ${ky}
                </td>
                <td>
                    ${val.Item_name}
                </td>
            </tr>
        `);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cust_items">
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I have updated my question with the appropriate structure as it is.

Comment: hi @gerry does this answer your question or have I missed something?

Comment: Yes. It has asnwered my question. Thank you very much!!

Comment: glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late to the party, but here's a fun and practical way to display your data dynamically using the [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) element and vanilla JS.

The in-code comments should make clear how it works.

Note: Be wary of adding the `id` attribute to elements inside a template (or inside a loop for that matter) cuz duplicate `id` values are bad.

```js
const data = {
  "John Doe" :
    [
      { "Item_id" : 1, "Item_name": "abc" },
      { "Item_id" : 2, "Item_name": "def" }
    ],
    "Jane Doe" : [
      { "Item_id" : 3, "Item_name": "ghi" },
      { "Item_id" : 4,  "Item_name": "jkl" }
    ]
};

// Identifies HTML elements and an array of the names
const
  container = document.getElementsByClassName("cust_items")[0],
  template = document.getElementById("group_template"),
  names = Object.keys(data);

// Loops through the names and adds a new copy of the template's contents for each one
for (let name of names){

  // Identifies HTML elements (Technically, some are `document fragments`)
  const
    copyOfTemplate = document.importNode(template.content, true),
    header = copyOfTemplate.querySelector(".header"),
    tbody = copyOfTemplate.querySelector("tbody");

  // Sets the header for the new copy of the template's contents
  header.innerHTML = name;
  
  // Loops through the items for this name and makes a new row for each one
  for(let item of data[name]){

    // Identifies strings and new HTML elements
    const
      itemId = item["Item_id"],
      itemName = item["Item_name"],
      row = document.createElement("TR"),
      idCell = document.createElement("TD"),
      nameCell = document.createElement("TD");
    
    // Sets the item number and item name in their respective cells
    idCell.innerHTML = itemId;
    nameCell.innerHTML = itemName;

    // Adds the cells to the new row
    row.appendChild(idCell);
    row.appendChild(nameCell);

    // Adds the new row to the `tbody` within the new copy of the template's contents
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  }
  
  // The new copy is ready to go live -- adds it to the page
  container.appendChild(copyOfTemplate);
}
```

```css
.header{ font-size: 1.2em; margin-bottom: 0.3em; }
table{ margin-left: 0.3em; margin-top: 0; border-collapse: collapse; }
th, td{ padding: 0.3em 0.5em; }
```

```html
<div class="cust_items"></div>

<template id="group_template">
  <h4 class="header"></h4>                  
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Item No.</th>
      <th>Item Name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
  <hr />
</template>
```